# Simple Audio Units Host to drive an Audio Units Instrument

Tags: python, core-audio, audiounit

I have to generate the audio for many isolated notes, chords and melodies using a sampled instrument. What would be the easiest way to programmatically do so (I don't want to manually enter the notes in a DAW then bounce the audio)? I found this [Python Audio Unit Host](https://github.com/simlmx/pyau) on GitHub but it is not actively maintained and it doesn't compile under Yosemite. Creating even a simple Audio Units Host in Objective-C seems like a daunting task. Any easier alternative?

Answer (score 1):

There's always apple's [Music Player](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicPlayerServices_Reference/index.html). It sets up an AUGraph with a sampler unit automatically.  There's a lot of C though, and configuring the sampler to use your files is a huge pain. But it's fairly straightforward to sequence the audio samples once it's set up.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the Python Audio Unit Host to support Yosemite https://github.com/johndpope/pyau
Have a look at the simonTest.cpp

```
CFStringRef theBaseStr = CFSTR("file:///Users/johnpope/Documents/gitWorkspace/pyau/");
CFStringRef theRelativeStr = CFSTR("test1.wav");
CFURLRef theBaseURL = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, theBaseStr, NULL);
CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathExtension(NULL, theBaseURL, theRelativeStr);
host2.BounceToFile(url,kAudioFormatLinearPCM,kAudioFileWAVEType); // warning - check the
```

Apple should release the AU Labs code code. - but it doesn't really fit into their objective c / swift categories.  If you have a spare apple support ticket - I'd urge to do so. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/AudioUnitDevelopmentFundamentals/AudioUnitDevelopmentFundamentals.html

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Have you tested it with Python 3 as well? My main system is Anaconda + Python 3.4, and the project fails to build with similar errors to the original one. The author suggests it's because of Python 3. I still have to find the time to build an environment with Python 2 without messing my main installation.

Comment: can't help with nix systems - I did push the intel egg file to this branch https://github.com/johndpope/pyau/tree/bDistributionFile